# Possible CORS error when looping between Twilio Functions and an external php endpoint

Tags: javascript, php, xml, http, twilio

We're working on a looping alert system that sends an alert to our agent, then sends a request to our external PHP endpoint to sleep for an interval, then the endpoint calls our Twilio Function/Twilio Runtime Domain Endpoint again with an AJAX request to issue an alert, and loops.

Function A --> External Sleep Function (/Sleep) --> Function A

That's the flow that we need, and we can't get it to work. We can receive the request from **Function A** at **/Sleep**, but then can't get it back to **Function A**. We can also send request from the **browser** to **/Sleep**, then receive the request back at **Function A**, then receive at **/Sleep** but still can't get it back to **Function A**.

Basically, we can't get the loop to complete. Does anyone have experience making a system like this work?

Additional context: Our PHP endpoint (`/Sleep`) is sleeping for 3 seconds (3000 ms) for testing purposes. Sending a browser or curl request to `/Sleep` effectively fires a request that we receive at `/Function-A`, but once our `/Function-A` tries to send another request to `/Sleep`, the loop breaks. Here's our code at `/Sleep`:

```
    <script>
        function sleep(ms) {
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        }
    
        async function twilioSleep() {
            await sleep( 3000 ); // 900000 = 15 min
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const url='https://our-service.twil.io/alert';
            Http.open( 'GET', url );
            Http.send();
        }

        twilioSleep();
    </script>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: (1) Similar case should work `if you coded well` (I have created similar infinite looping with sleep in-between in both server side programs and even in smartphone apps). Please tell us how do you do the sleep function in the php and how do you trigger the AJAX you mentioned (i.e. show your code please). (2) please tell us the time interval you set in the sleep part -- is it very short such as one or two seconds ??

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Functions have a timeout of 10 seconds and will not run beyond that. Also, once a Twilio Function either completes (you call the `callback` function) or is terminated, then any network connections it has open are also terminated.

So, if you are making the request from the Twilio Function to your `/Sleep` endpoint, but the `/Sleep` endpoint doesn't return a response until it has finished sleeping, then I would suggest that the Twilio Function is timing out, terminating the connection with your server and stopping the loop.

For this to work with Twilio Functions your PHP server will have to return a response to the Twilio Function immediately and perform the sleep asynchronously somehow. You could achieve this with a job scheduler or perhaps an asynchronous PHP library like [spatie/async](https://github.com/spatie/async) or [coroutine](https://symplely.github.io/coroutine/). I'm not a PHP programmer, so I don't have a concrete recommendation, but hopefully these ideas help.

**Edit**

Ok, so based on the code in the question, the issue is that your PHP server is returning HTML and JavaScript to perform the sleep and make the next request. When you request that page with the browser, the browser interprets the JavaScript and makes the request. When the Twilio Function requests your `/Sleep` endpoint, it receives the HTML response and does not interpret it and run the JavaScript because it is not a browser. I do not know how that works with curl, but I suspect it really doesn't.

If you want your PHP server to sleep then make a new request, then you will need to implement that in PHP. To start with, the [`sleep` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) should help, and here's an article on [ways to make HTTP requests in PHP](https://www.twilio.com/blog/5-ways-to-make-http-requests-in-php).

But, as you work on this, remember that Twilio Functions will still have a 10 second timeout and if you sleep your PHP function longer than that then it will also get terminated. Unless you find a way to return a response to the Twilio Function and perform the sleep in the background, possibly using one of the async libraries I pointed to before, or a job scheduler.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks very much. So our PHP server actually sends a completely new request to our Twilio Function endpoint `/twilio-alert` after sleeping. We have print statements on the `/twilio-alert` side that never get hit. I hear you on the timeout, but we set our sleep to 3 seconds for testing and it never gets back to us. I'll add our javascript to the main question and some more context. Using curl or a browser request to our PHP server effectively triggers the function at `/twilio-alert`, but the Function A --> External Sleep Function (/Sleep) --> Function A flow doesn't.

Comment: I have updated my answer. TL;DR is that Twilio Functions will not interpret and run JavaScript that your server responds with, you will need to do the sleeping/requesting in PHP, not JS.